# Open excelfile with an preselected cell

Tags: java, excel

i have an application where i read an excelfile(.xls), make some calculations and present the result. At the result is a button implemented which opens the original excelfile.

Is it possible to provide the specific cell as an arguement to show the cell directly, so that the user does not have to select the cell by himself?

Comment: There is no such startup switch in Excel to give a default highlighted cell. Maybe you can embed a macro in the sheet (but I wouldn't do that).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Like Holger and Moritz said in their comments, it seems that that it is not possible to startup excel with a given cell preselected.

Answer (score 0):

The selected cell is stored within the Excel file. You have to study the API of your Excel writing library to find out, how to set this.

E.g. with POI it would be http://poi.apache.org/apidocs/org/apache/poi/xssf/usermodel/XSSFSheet.html#setActiveCell(java.lang.String)

Comment: It is an encrypted file, so iam not able to write it to the file system. My intention is just to open the excelfile at the desktop with a specific cell preselected.

Comment: I don’t know of such a switch. A list of available switches can be found here: http://office.microsoft.com/en-us/excel-help/command-line-switches-for-excel-HA010158030.aspx The only other way to accomplish the desired selection without changing the file would be through OLE/COM/etc interfaces which is something a Java programmer surely won’t like.